# JQuery Ajax call always hitting error with status code 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, status, deferred, promise

I have a fairly complicated set of scripts that works most of the time.  What I want to do is make AJAX requests and then do something if I get a 401 error.  When they get the 401, I send them to authenticate, then re-send the request.  I've added some handling to the ajaxPrefilter and it looks like this:

```
jqXhr.then(function (response, status) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        data = response && response.d ? response.d : response,
        result = data && _.isArray(data.results) ? data.results : data;

    deferred.resolveWith(this, [result, status, jqXhr, response]);

    return deferred;
},
function (response, status, error) {
    var secondPromise = $.Deferred();

    if (response.status == 401) {
         // handle authentication
         // resend request
         // depending on outcome, resolve or reject secondPromise
    } else {
         // not authentication issue, just reject the secondPromise
    }

    return secondPromise;
}).promise(jqXhr);
```

Basically, the first part of the "then" just resolves the deferred object and sends it back (so whoever is waiting for the call gets it right away).  The second part (the error) checks for error code of 401 (need authentication).  If it's a 401, it authenticates, re-sends the request, and handles the outcome.  If it's NOT a 401, it throws rejects it.

The problem is that the response, status, error arguments of the error function are ALWAYS as follows:

response = the deferred object with state of 0, status of 0, statusText of "error", and no response text.
status = "error"
error = ""

Is there some way that I'm missing to detect the error?  I can clearly see in firebug's net tab and in Fiddler that the response code is clearly 401.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Response status of zero is normally associated with the `file://` protocol. As far as I recall, you get zero under all circumstances. If necessary, then install WAPM (or its component parts separately), which will allow you to browse your web pages locally under the `http://` protocol.

Comment: Not using the file:// protocol, still stuck... :(

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Comment: No...  but I'm not stuck because I left that job, not because I solved the problem...